# How can I forward websocket request to Apache Tomcat from Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, tomcat, websocket, atmosphere

I have server setup like Apache2 + mod_jk + two instances of Tomcat (7.0.33). Now I am using atmosphere with tomcat. Atmosphere with long-polling is working just fine. But now I want to use web sockets as transport protocol in atmosphere. But it seems Apache is unable to forward request to Tomcat and it gives me error

> Can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost/Myapp/update/?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json.

Answer (score 3):

Since Apache 2.4.6, Apache httpd forwards/proxies websockets

Comment: This would be more suited to a comment rather than an answer. Once you [have enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), please consider moving this to a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't support WebSocket, so you need to use Ningx or HAProxy.

Comment: Thanks. But I just want apache to forward webscoket request to mod_jk and not to process them. So will nignix or HAProxy will help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

Mod_Jk implies in the translation of the request from the HTTP into AJP/13 protocol which implies that the web server should have some ability to handle/process the request.
You may be better served by using mod_proxy instead to establish the apache-tomcat communication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using a module called mod_proxy_wstunnel

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

I don't think this existed when the question was originally asked. In version 2.4.5 Apache added support for this mod.